# Using linter from WSL (Ubuntu for Windows) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pylint, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm setting up a Python environment in VS Code and have already installed [the plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python).

VSCode is suggesting that it can't run pylint:

[image]

However, pylint is installed in my local WSL (though not on Windows). If I click the `Install Pylint` button, the WSL terminal embedded in VSCode shows the following:

```
$ python -m pip install pylint
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in /home/mao/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

How do I get VS Code to use this installed pylint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Python interpreter you have selected for your workspace matches the one you want to have Pylint installed into (if you're running the latest version of the extension you can see it specified down in the status bar in the lower-left of your window). You can also set the [`python.pylint.pylintPath` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_pylint) to point to the `pylint` command location explicitly.

Do realize, though, that as of at least version 0.8.0, there isn't official support for WSL in the Python extension (yet, although it is [planned](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67)).